# How to use same connection of connection pool in different modules with multithreading?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, oop, module

I have to speed up inserts at my MySQL table, currently I have 6 inserts per second, but I need around 60 per second, because I have to analyze characteristics of about 300,000 cars using Python and insert the corresponding characteristics of each car in the database.

I'm using 4 different modules to do the job:

1. module1 - Connections manager
2. module2 - Main module, that has all cars information and create multiple threads.
3. module3 - Module that has some functions which module2 use when analyzing each car. This module send queries to db each time it is used.
4. module4  - Module that has some functions that module3 use. This module also send queries to db each time it is used.

During my research to speed up the job, I found the best solution in my case is to use threading, This way I can analyze many cars at the same time, each tread analyzing one car in parallel, doing their queries in db in parallel to find infos about the car and then save the characteristics of the car in the db.

The problem is if I open and close connection each time module3 and module4 are used by treads, it takes to much time, the process to open connection take to much time, to work which multi threading I had to create a connection pull, for best organization I have decided to create a separate module (module1) which create a connection pool and menage the connections, I want to create the connection on the module 1 and import the connection in the module 3 and in the module4, the problem is I don't know how to do each to each thread use always the same connection independent of the module, e.g thread1 use cnx1  in all the modules, thread2 use cnx2 in all the modules. This is the best approach to the problem and how can I do it? My module 1 code is below.

Note: I'm already storing some quantity of cars in memory and inserting by executemany to enhance the insert speed.

````
class CompanyDB:
    db = 'company_name'
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnx_pool = None

    def create_pool(self):
        if self.cnx_pool is not None:
            print('database pool already created, using same pool')
            return self.cnx_pool
        else:
            self.cnx_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="xxxx",
                                                                  pool_size=10,
                                                                  pool_reset_session=True,
                                                                  host='xxxx.com',
                                                                  database='xxxx',
                                                                  user='xxxx',
                                                                  password='xxxx')
            print('created autoexp pool')
            return self.cnx_pool


    def close(self):
        self.close()
        print('connection closed')


    def get_cnx_from_pool(self):
            cnx  = self.cnx_pool.get_connection()
            print('got connection of company db')
            return cnx

```
````

Comment: It sounds like you are instantiating multiple instances of `CompanyDB`, each managing a pool of 1 connection. There should be one instance of this object shared by multiple modules (it could be global variable in a module the users all import... or have a factory function that creates the instance on first call) and that object should have a `pool_size=` to the number of connections you want.

Comment: Hello @tdelaney, i was using pool_size=1 just while developing, to do not create too many connections with database whille debuging and turn the database slow, already edited the post and changed the pool_size = 10. I'm stantiating just one time    CompanyDB, but i dont know how to do to thread1 use the cnx1 in all modules, thread2 use cnx2 in all modules... can show me an example of code how to do it?

Comment: I think I misread your question. You want thread1 to always use the same connection even as it calls different modules. The easiest way to do that would be to skip a connection pool entirely and make sure the the connection to use is always passed to the functions in the different modules you call. Alternately you could use [Thread-Local Data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) which is like a global variable but gets a different object per thread.

Comment: I suggest reading documentation on [bulk loading inserts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html) and [bulk loading innodb](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) to complement your threads to gain the performance. I recommend including `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` and the insertion code into your question.